# Windows Server Permissions: What permission changes are needed to run 'sqlcmd' through IUSR?

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-permissions

A little background: I need to invoke sqlcmd to remotely run .sql files via PHP. I am trying to use this function call: `exec("sqlcmd -?", $second);` There is zero output after running this command. Running this command under my current user works fine.

PHP runs under IUSR according to PHP's `get_current_user();` function so it would be logical to change the permissions on sqlcmd to allow PHP to run sqlcmd (I give full permissions temporarily just for testing):

[image]

Then I retest the PHP script and again no output. I decide to restart IIS. Still no output.

What permissions are needed to run sqlcmd under IUSR?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but it is very unlikely to have anything to do with the permissions on the executable file.  You only need "read & execute" to run an executable.  Either the executable isn't being found, or it is failing silently for some reason.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Could it be that SqlCmd uses other libraries located on other parts of the hard drive? Or is that unlikely?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable guess.  If so, the most likely cause is that the PATH environment variable doesn't include all the necessary directories.  You could also use Process Monitor to see what SqlCmd is doing, that might give you a useful clue.